# How to get Kitchen named parameters to work on Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, cygwin, pentaho

Need help with run a Kettle job with a named parameter ("InputDate") on Windows using Kitchen.

This works great on Linux:

`kitchen.sh -file:ingest.kjb -param:InputDate=2017-07-10`.

But I cannot get this working on Windows. I have tried under Cygwin64 and also the Command prompt in Windows. In either case the job just cannot receive the parameter.

I believe the *hyphens* and *equal signs* are problematic in Windows. So, per the Kettle docs, you can replace '-' with '/' and you can replace '=' with ':'.

But in the case of named parameters it is impossible to replace the equal sign since this does not work in the command line `/param:InputDate:2017-07-10`

I have tried the all of the following

- `/param:InputDate:2017-07-10`
- `/param:InputDate 2017-07-10`
- `/param:InputDate=2017-07-10`
- `-param:InputDate 2017-07-10`
- `-param:InputDate=2017-07-10`

an either get this error:

```
2017/08/25 17:17:08 - Kitchen - ERROR (version 7.1.0.0-12, build 1 from 2017-05-16 17.18.02 by buildguy) : Command Line Options
```

or get this exception:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Central Log Store is not initialized!!!
```

What is the proper way to pass a named parameter to Kitchen in Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows CMD the following syntax should work:

```
kitchen.bat /file:ingest.kjb "/param:InputDate=2017-07-10"
```

Comment: Thanks that works under CMD so answered the question. But I guess Cygwin is not supported since still get exception there.